# module 'name' has no attribute 'class'

Tags: python, module

I imported a module in python as follow

```
import sdds
```

This module contains the class SDDS:

```
class SDDS:
     """This class implements SDDS datasets."""

     def __init__(self, index=0):
          #define common SDDS definitions
          self.SDDS_VERBOSE_PrintErrors = 1
          self.SDDS_EXIT_PrintErrors = 2
          self.SDDS_CHECK_OKAY = 0
          self.SDDS_CHECK_NONEXISTENT = 1
          self.SDDS_CHECK_WRONGTYPE = 2
          self.SDDS_CHECK_WRONGUNITS = 3
          self.SDDS_DOUBLE = 1
          self.SDDS_REAL64 = 1
```

I tried in PyCarm:

```
 import sdds
 from sdds import SDDS

 fi = sdds.SDDS(0)
 fi.load(fname)
```

But i got the error massages

```
 module 'sdds' has no attribute 'SDDS'
```

How can i import the SDDS class and use it ?

Comment: Will doing `from ssds import *` change the error message?

Comment: the import statements seem redundant. In your example, delete the `import sdds` statement and try this again

Comment: Also, on which line does the error happen?

Comment: @Leo, using from sdds import * doesn't change the error .

Comment: @Leo The error happens when i call a function inside another module having these line 
 fi = sdds.SDDS(0)
 fi.load(fname)

Comment: @Ian I tried this but i still see the same error, 
Should i have the sdds module in the same directory as my pycharm script?

Comment: FWIW, the [sdds module on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sdds/) doesn't appear to have an SDDS class.

Comment: If you are (unintentionally) trying to shadow a "global" `sdds` module in your search path with a "local" module also named `sdds`, the absolute imports will import the global one, not the local one.

Comment: @ely66 Assuming that you wrote a module `sdds` (a file called `sdds.py`) yourself, it's probably easiest for you to have it in the same directory as the script that references it. 
You should definitely remove either the first line `import sdds` or the second `from sdds import SDDS`, to not confuse yourself with namespaces.

**EDIT**: It appears (see comment by @chepner) that there is a module sdds (the one from PYPI?) that is also loaded. In that case probably try renaming your module `sdds.py` for something like `mysdds.py` and import via `from mysdds import SDDS`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find how to import on Pycharm with this link: https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-install-a-library-on-pycharm/
You must install the lib in Pycharm before import in your code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).